# "With" block in D language

Tags: d, with-statement

Is a classic `with` block available in D language?

I am looking for the following behavior:

```
struct Address {
  string street;
  int number;
}

struct Person {
  Address address;
}

// in some function
Person p = ...
with(p.address) {
  street = "Wide St.";
  number = 123;
}

// I am open to other solutions, if they could work e.g.
p.address.with => { street = ...; number = ...; }

assert(p.address.street == "Wide St.");
```

If it's not available, how would you update several fields of a nested struct? In C++ I'd assign the nested to a reference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why don't you consult the [D Language Reference](http://dlang.org/language-reference.html)? With just few clicks I found http://dlang.org/statement#WithStatement, which answers your question.
If you are lazy to follow the link, here is the short answer: *yes, D has the [with statement](http://dlang.org/statement#WithStatement), and it behaves exactly as you want*.